# Is it possible to access phone camera in system / pc browser

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, html, jquery-mobile

Recently we worked on reading a QR code in our website, with manual focus camera in the System browser (Chrome) and the same is tested with Mobile browser (chrome) with mobile camera. We succeed in doing it but, according to the end user feed back its actually taking time to read/scan with manual focus camera and its easy with mobile camera. But as per our requirement we need to implement it on PC browser with manual focus camera.

Is there any way that we can use Mobile device camera to integrate with the PC browser. Currently we are working with few JAVA based mobiles which allow mobile camera to use as web cam. Any help would be appreciated to crack this.

Answer (score 0):

what I have used is cordova has many plugins that can consume using Javascript or if you use angularjs there is a version called ng-cordova.

Cordova https://cordova.apache.org/

Ng-cordova: http://ngcordova.com/

I hope that will help.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use Mobile Camera With PC Browser But It Is Difficult

Step:

Write An Application To Capture Picture From Phone And Send It To Browser .

Phone And PC Should Be At Same Network And Phone Accessed From Browser with It Local IP address To Get Pictures .

Users Most Install Your Application On They Phones And Set Static IP Adderss For Phones Example 192.168.1.100

In Website You Most Get Picture From 192.168.1.100 And Show It.